# How to import a resource with special characters created by a for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

How to import a resource created by a for_each and it has special characters?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using **single quotes** ( ' ) in the resource name and **escaped double quotes** ( \" ) in the index:

```
terraform import 'aws_instance.server[\"Instance: special (myCorp)\"]' i-000111222
```

I hope this helps a lot!